# Estimates from a log-linear regression model

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, panel-data

I am estimating a economic growth regressions using dynamic panel data.
My specification is as folllows:

$$\ln Y_{i,t} = a \ln Y_{i,t-1} + bX_{i,t} + e_{i,t}$$

- $Y$ measures income per capita
- $X$ is the independent variable of interest, which represents a certain share of GDP (e.g. 0.05)

From the specification it follows that I am estimating the effect on economic growth as well:

$$\ln Y_{i,t} - \ln Y_{i,t-1} = (a-1) \ln Y_{i,t-1} + bX_{i,t} + e_{i,t}$$

After running the model, the estimate for $b$ is 0.07. Can someone help me interpret this estimate? I would like to know what the change in growth rate is following from this 0.07.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking for.

Comment: My question is: how do i interpret the estimate b. Does this mean that a 1 percentage point increase in X, increases the growth rate by 0.07 percentage points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I interpret $b$? Does this mean that a 1 percentage point increase in X, increases the growth rate by 0.07 percentage points?

A 1 percentage point increase in X increases the difference in the log of $Y$ by 0.07 percentage points (*on average*), for $Y_{i,t-1}$ held constant. If you think of the difference in the log of $Y$ as growth rate (which it *sort of* is), then yes.